# How to load image to WPF in runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems like it's quite complicated to load an image in runtime to a WPF window.

```
Image image;
image = new Uri("Bilder/sas.png", UriKind.Relative);
????.Source = new BitmapImage(image);
```

I'm trying this code, but I need some help to get it to work. I get some red lines below the code! I also wonder if I need to add some extra code inside the XAML code or is in enough with this:

```
<Image Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="image1" 
       Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" />
```

Wonder because I have seen examples with sorces to the images inside the XAML tags.

EDIT:

I'm using this now:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/sas.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
image1.Source = bitmap;
```

The XAML:

```
<Grid Width="374">
    <Image Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" />
    <Button Content="Start" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,226,0,0" Name="btnStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Land" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,226,0,0" Name="btnLand" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,226,0,0" Name="cmbChangeRoute" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" />
</Grid>
```

EDIT 2:
My issue is solved, this code works fine:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + company + ".png"));
image2.Source = image;
```

Comment: Those first two lines of code can't be right; a Uri is NOT an Image.

Comment: Thanks! But know it complain about the path! It's looking for the path at C: when it should be bin/debug!?

Answer (score 49):

In WPF an image is typically loaded from a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f86tw9e) or an [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a).

[BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218) supports both and an Uri can even be passed as constructor argument:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://...");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

If the image file is located in a local folder, you would have to use a `file://` Uri. You could create such a Uri from a path like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Bilder", "sas.png");
var uri = new Uri(path);
```

If the image file is an assembly resource, the Uri must follow the the [Pack Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) scheme:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Bilder/sas.png");
```

In this case the Visual Studio Build Action for `sas.png` would have to be `Resource`.

Once you have created a `BitmapImage` and also have an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control like in this XAML

```
<Image Name="image1" />
```

you would simply assign the BitmapImage to the `Source` property of that Image control:

```
image1.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: But what about the code in XAML?! Like this: <Image Name="Image1" />

Comment: No I missed that! Well since I hade a folder like that in the bin/debug it should work? But know I'm trying to get it work from the resources and would preciate some help to get it to work? To start, I guess I dont need any extra in the XAML code, since the image already has a name: image1 ??

Comment: A folder in bin/Debug is not sufficient. It would have to be in your VS project, as I said. And the XAML `<Image Name="image1" ... />` creates a member variable named `image1` of type [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), which is a WPF control, not a bitmap/image.

Comment: I'm using your code, but I only get an error about Uri prefix is not recognised !?

Comment: Following your last edit, you use `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/sas.png")`. This would require the file `sas.png` to be part of your VS project with Build Action `Resource`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm using the another code! See my second edit.

Comment: There's no need for the BeginInit and EndInit. Simply use the `BitmapImage(Uri)` constructor. Otherwise that code is *in no way* different from what I answered here, except the the folder is called `Resources`, not `Bilder`.

Comment: Have another Nice Answer badge!

Comment: Single most useful answer anywhere on SO for specifying image source at runtime. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your `sas.png` is marked as `Build Action: Content` and `Copy To Output Directory: Copy Always` in its Visual Studio `Properties`...

I think the C# source code goes like this...

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString("pack://application:,,,/Bilder/sas.png") as ImageSource;
```

and XAML should be

```
<Image Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" 
       Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Source="../Bilder/sas.png"
       Width="350" />
```

**EDIT**

Dynamically I think XAML would provide best way to load Images ...

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyImageSourceConverter}}"
       x:Name="MyImage"/>
```

where `image.DataContext` is `string` path.

```
MyImage.DataContext = "pack://application:,,,/Bilder/sas.png";

public class MyImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value_, Type targetType_, 
    object parameter_, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture_)
    {
        return (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString (value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now as you set a different data context, `Image` would be automatically loaded at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, but if I want to load different images during runtime. When I create a object of the WPF window I want to pass different images, then I guess the XAML code would look different? I have saved all the images in a filder inside Bin/Debug, OK?

Comment: Thanks! But isn't his way to complicated to just use some images!?

Comment: :) Thats how we would do in WPF... if you dont want XAML then use the C# code I originally gave.... `image.Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString("pack://application:,,,/Bilder/sas.png" ) as ImageSource;`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm using the another code! See my second edit.

Comment: Think you mean value_.ToString()

Comment: This answer was posted like 10y ago and it just fixed my problem!! Thank you