# How to set ImageSource in a codebehindfile

Tags: wpf, image, code-behind, imagesource

I have in a UserControl the Property `ImageSource`. How can I set the `ImageSource` in my code behind to a Image in my Resources directory?

I want to bind the Image Source to the property `ImageSource`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" />
```

Comment: @Clemens sry, it's an typo, i mean `ImageSource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218) (which is derived from ImageSource) from a resource file in code, you would do the following, provided that the file `MyImage.jpg` is in a folder named `Images` of your Visual Studio project, and that its `Build Action` is set to `Resource`:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/MyImage.jpg"); 
ImageSource = new BitmapImage(uri); // set the ImageSource property
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881612/1136211).

---

You could also directly use the image resource without binding:

```
<Image Source="/Images/MyImage.jpg" />
```