# Change LargeImageSourse in WPF from CodeBehind using vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm new in WPF and I start to use the ribbon:RibbonButton as follows:

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="ServerCondition" Label="Server" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="0" Height="50" CornerRadius="10" LargeImageSource="/Economy;component/Images/server_down.ico"/>
```

Now it comes to change the LargeImageSourse with another one dynamically from code behind.
First of all I don't know if that is posible.
And if it isn't posible... what control I may use to have the ability to change the icon? 
If there is someone to assist me, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code behind, you can change it like so:

`ServerCondition.LargeImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your uri"));`

[How to load image to WPF in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880946/how-to-load-image-to-wpf-in-runtime)