# Can't load default image in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I made a code that insert an image in the DataGrid, and all working good. This is insert the image:

```
`return SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData((string)value)));`
```

the variable `value` contain a link of a shield downloaded through internet. Now the problem is that some link are correct but the online resource is missing, so I get 404. I want to show a default image if the online resource is unavailable. I've tryed like this:

```
        try
        {
            return SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData((string)value)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + value.ToString() + Resources.generic.GetType());
            return Resources.generic;
        }
        return null;
```

I've insert in the resources of my project a default image called `"generic.png"`, but when the code enter in the catch in the DataGrid doesn't appear no image. 
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Please view my modified answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your PNG picture to BitmapImage instance. Please view [How to load image to WPF in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880946/how-to-load-image-to-wpf-in-runtime) topic

Also, if value is null, the line

```
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + value.ToString() + Resources.generic.GetType());
```

will throw new NullReferenceException, and your Image's Source will be null. In your previous question I wrote how to handle the case when value is null or empty.

**EXAMPLE**

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/folders/names/generic.png");
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Comment: No. Not Bitmap, but BitmapImage, it's a different thing.

Comment: I mean the link is never null, perhaps only in some cases. But let's say I have a link www.link.com that contains the image, but the image is not available because it has been removed, but the link is still valid. Only I get an exception because obviously you can not scarciare image.

Comment: I got it, in this case you caught the exception correctly, but you still have to handle the case when value is null.

Comment: Sure, could you show me how to convert the image from resource?

Comment: Please look at example

Comment: I already look this, but I not have an url, I've an image saved into the resource of the application.

Comment: Yes, and you can access this resource with URI, not only with Resources

Comment: Ok, but there's a way to get the correct URI? Because I get this exception "can't find the resource". This is my URI: var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SF_DebugProject;component/folders/names/generic.png");

Comment: Replace "folders/names" with folder name in your project where generic.png is located. If generic.png is in project without any folders, your uri will be var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SF_DebugProject;component/generic.png"‌​);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83466/discussion-between-harold-finch-and-vmaleev).