# Environment.CurrentDirectory returns correct path from exe, but not from IDE

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a couple of files in my project folder, in [myproject]/images

When I run my C# app, I post-build copy these to [myproject]/Debug/images...

as I run the app, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns the correct path

but, **inside the IDE, it does not** return the correct directory when I edit the WPF template

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "images", "someimage.png");
var uri = new Uri(path);
imageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

I also tried this :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
```

it's even worst since it lands in my documents and settings

how can I figure the correct folder path inside the IDE ?

[edit:]

workaround, so I dont get an exeption in the XAML editor

```
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/someimage.png");
    if (uri != null)
    {
        someimage= new BitmapImage(uri);
        ...
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   ...
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all, instead of making the image files assembly resources?

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881612/1136211). In short, add the image files to some folder (e.g. "images") in your Visual Studio project, set their Build Action to Resource, and load them by a Resource File Pack URI: `var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/someimage.png");`. No need to copy the files anywhere.

Comment: How does your post build step look like?

Comment: I removed it, I use assembly resources as Clemens suggested but it still does not work in the ide, which is strange since I can add an Image tag in the xaml, it finds the imagebut inside my custom control, it does not find the image, unless I run the project

Comment: You always need to use the relative path to the image when using resources. Using [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as already recommended is the safest especially when the resources is declared in a different assembly.

Comment: I tried relative path, I get  'A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.'

Comment: I edited my question with a workaround,... so much for the Xaml editor

Comment: As a note, checking if an Uri that you just created is `null` makes no sense. You may just write `someimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/someimage.png"));`

Answer (score 1):

you can do without .exe path at all, if use `UriKind.Relative` (relative to the current directory)

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("images", "some_image.png");
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: it does not work, I just get a more detailed error, but it still points to the parent of my application solution, so it does not find the 'images' folder....I'll check what Clemens suggetsts